# How to overwrite the content on running executable(.exe) file

Tags: python, executable, updates

I want my application to be able to update itself, here is what i have already tried.

```
import nettell, ftpfm, os, shutil
def downupg():
#       DOWNLOADING UPDATES
    try:
        if nettell.tell() == True:
                ftpfm.retrive() 
                shutil.copy2('C:\\Program Files\\myapp\\update\\update.exe', 'C:\\Program Files\\myapp\\myrunningapp.exe')
    except Exception, ex:
            print str(ex)

#myrunningapp.exe is the exe file which download update and overwrite itself
#update.exe is the downloaded update file
```

where **nettell** check if there is network connection and it contain

```
#!C:\python27\python.exe
#Python network module
import socket
def tell():
    try:
        if len(socket.gethostbyname('www.google.com')) != 0:
            return True
    except Exception, e:
        return False
tell()
```

and **ftpfm** contain

```
import ftplib
import os

path = '/myappupdates'
filename = 'update.exe'
def retrive():
    ftp = ftplib.FTP("ftp.myftpserver.com") 
    ftp.login("myusername", "mypassword") 
    ftp.cwd(path)
    ftp.retrbinary("RETR %s" % filename,open('C:\\Program Files\\myapp\\update'+'\\'+filename, 'wb').write)
    ftp.quit()
```

nettell and ftpfm doesn't to have any problems except that am getting permission denied exception when try to copy new content from(C:\Program Files\myapp\update\update.exe) to a running exe file(C:\Program Files\myapp\myrunningapp.exe) and am getting this.

```
[Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Program Files\\myapp\\myrunningapp.exe'
```

i tried to find answers from the internet and i got  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25745601/permission-to-overwrite-files)  which didn't help me. Is there any way i can update my application from within itself.?

Comment: i believe the usual approach is to have a separate update executable which gets called by the main executable, this then checks for updates, downloads them and then shuts down the main process to allow the executable to be replaced. of course the update executable must be run with sufficient permission (admin) to be able to write to the program files directory

Comment: Well thank you so much. Can you please suggest me the best site to get that tutarial @ James Kent

Comment: i've not read a tutorial about it,it's just been my experience with many pieces of software that have built in update facilities. the reason being that you cannot replace an executable file while it is being executed

Comment: Yes, when an executable is running its file is locked. So you need a different program to change it when it isnt running.